# Jboss add-user non interactive way with receiving secret identity

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to add a management user for my domain like this:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-domain-configuration?showall=

I would like to create the user non interactive way with command line and receive back the secret identity as a result but I can't find any args in the documentations that would support this feature. Is it possible or I should look for an other workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find any workaround @erik.c ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but the secret identity returned is the base64 encoded password I set for the user so I could generate it other way.